# how to create html table with dates in headers using javascript .....where dates are retrieved from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I create an HTML table with dates in headers using Javascript, .....where dates are retrieved from json?

Below is the json that is retrieved from a service and the values of "day" must be the columns in html table. The table should look like:

### sccode  sheettype    8-3      1-3

```
gtbb        pt       717      1127   
delh        ut       2090
```

```js
[{
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 717,
    "scannedSheetCount": 717,
    "day": "8-3"
 }, {
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 1127,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1127,
    "day": "1-3"
 }, {
    "sccode": "DELH",
    "sheetType": "UT",
    "sheetCount": 2090,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1171,
    "day": "8-3"
 }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: the table structure is not reflected by the json structure in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Code : (but no gestion of duplicate "day" like "8-3" in your example)

```js
var json = [{
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 717,
    "scannedSheetCount": 717,
    "day": "8-3"
 }, {
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 1127,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1127,
    "day": "1-3"
 }, {
    "sccode": "DELH",
    "sheetType": "UT",
    "sheetCount": 2090,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1171,
    "day": "8-3"
 }];
 
 var tableHeader = '<tr>',
     tableRow1 = '<tr>',
     tableRow2 = '<tr>';
 
 for( var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++ ){
  var value = json[i];
  
  tableHeader += '<th>' + value.day + '</th>';
    tableRow1 += '<td>' + value.sccode + '</td>';
    tableRow2 += '<td>' + value.sheetType + '</td>';
 }
 
 tableHeader += '</tr>';
 tableRow1 += '</tr>';
 tableRow2 += '</tr>';
 
 var table = '<table>' +
    tableHeader +
            tableRow1 +
            tableRow2 +
          '</table>';
 
 $("#mytable").html( table );
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytable"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response...but the "day" should not be duplicated in the columns...i will edit question so that u may understand the expected output better

Comment: Can you be more specific : we don't see 123, 256, 45, "ccuk", "lt", 231, 123 and 32 in your json but you mention it in your html table.

Comment: there are some branch codes like "delh"...which come under the header "sccode" and its type "ut" which come under the header "sheet type" on date (dates like 8-3,1-3 etc should be the headers)  "8-3"   has 2090 total sheets and 1171 scanned sheets

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure is like

`[name, age, date1, date2,...,dateN]`

the data source hydrating the table should have the same model.

From the json you have described, I can't find a source for `name` and `age` fields so I will ignore that aspect and just show you a transformation for `date`.

You can have more items in your json for the same date, it seems, so you will need to parse the json and `group by` `date`.

```js
var columns = [],
  transformedData = [],
  jsonData = [{
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 717,
    "scannedSheetCount": 717,
    "day": "8-3"
  }, {
    "sccode": "GTBB",
    "sheetType": "PT",
    "sheetCount": 1127,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1127,
    "day": "1-3"
  }, {
    "sccode": "DELH",
    "sheetType": "UT",
    "sheetCount": 2090,
    "scannedSheetCount": 1171,
    "day": "8-3"
  }];

$.each(jsonData, function(key, item) {
  var keyDate = item.day;

  // check if column does not exist
  if (columns.indexOf(keyDate) === -1) {
    columns.push(keyDate);
  }
});
// here we have all the distinct columns dates existent
// now you need to build up the transformedData
// and that is something only you understand how it will happen

// some loop on j
var row = [],
  i;

for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  row.push('something for date ' + columns[i]); // and a function of j
}
transformedData.push(row);
// end of loop of j

// now we have date columns and transformed data
// so we can build the table
var table = $('<table>');


var thead = $('<thead>'),
  theadInnerHtml = [];
var tbody = $('<tbody>'),
  tbodyInnerHtml = [];

// attach head and body to the table and table to the document
thead.appendTo(table);
tbody.appendTo(table);
table.appendTo(document.body);

// the header
theadInnerHtml.push('<tr>');
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  var d = new Date(),
    key = columns[i].split('-'); //day-month

  d.setDate(key[0]);
  d.setMonth(key[1] - 1); // months are 0 index based

  theadInnerHtml.push('<td>');
  theadInnerHtml.push(d.getDate() + '/' + Number(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getYear());
  theadInnerHtml.push('</td>');
}
theadInnerHtml.push('</tr>');
thead.html(theadInnerHtml.join(''));


// the body
for (j = 0; j < transformedData.length; j++) {
  var r = [];

  r.push('<tr>');
  for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    r.push('<td>');
    r.push(transformedData[j][i]);
    r.push('</td>');
  }
  tbodyInnerHtml.push(r.join(''));
}
tbody.html(tbodyInnerHtml.join(''));
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

thead td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

tbody td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @bluehipy....i have edited the question i have asked and i hope u will understand the output that is expected.

Comment: what is 123 meaning for 8-3 and GTBB? anyway if you still don't get how to do it you probable have other things you miss, programming knowledge wise :)

Comment: gtbb is a branch code,8-3 is date and 123 is just number of sheets that are scanned or total number of sheets